# aestus immanes -- parsing a sentence from Augustine's Confessions

Tags: grammar-identification

Please consider this passage from Book III, chapter 2 of Augustine's *Confessions*:

> Ut quid decurrit in torrentem picis bullientis, aestus immanes taetrarum libidinum, in quos ipsa mutatur et vertitur per nutum proprium de caelesti serenitate detorta atque deiecta?

How would you parse *aestus immanes*?  Could we say it's accusative plural in apposition to *torrentem*?  The implicit subject of *decurrit* is *vena amicitiae* (mentioned a sentence or two before the quoted passage).  Augustine is discussing how the *vena amicitiae* has been distorted in him.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right that *aestus immanes* is in apposition to *torrentem*.

*Aestus* is 4th declension and (with the ambiguous length of the final -us) has *many* possible parsings. Combined with the *immanes*, however, the possibilities reduce somewhat: nominative, accusative, and vocative plural.

The only possibility that makes sense is accusative. There is no plural verb with which it could agree as a nominative subject. Furthermore, *aestus immanes* clearly develops the same idea in the phrase *torrentem picis bullientis*.